# Println as argument in groovy script

Tags: groovy

I have one groovy script which print some statistics: println: "..."

now I have another groovy script which needs this data. Is possible somehow run first script from second and save this data as paramater and then work with them from second script ? I just know how to run script: with `GroovyShell()` and then `run(...)`  but this doesnt return output of first script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options:

1. If you're calling it from a script, redefine `stdout`.
2. Fix the first script so it prints data retrieved from a class, and re-write the calling script to use that class instead of relying on the printed output from the first. Long-term may be the best option.
3. Use a pipe on the command line: `groovy s1.groovy | groovy s2.groovy`

Personally, when composing things that do stuff with stdin/stdio, I prefer the last method. Example:

**s1.groovy**

```
5.times { println it }
```

**s2.groovy**

```
r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
while (l = r.readLine()) { println((l as Integer) * 2) }
```

**Output**

```
$ groovy s1.groovy 
0
1
2
3
4
$ groovy s1.groovy | groovy s2.groovy 
0
2
4
6
8
```

Comment: thx a lot 3. I will use last method but I have to change conditional in your while block to  (( line = r.readLine() ) != null) because in my output is just println and then this cycle stops.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to set the `out` parameter in the binding when calling the first script:

So given a script `s1.groovy`:

```
//Print the letters of 'tim_yates', one per line
'tim_yates'.each this.&println
```

We can do (in `s2.groovy`)

```
// Create a StringWriter that will capture output
String output = new StringWriter().with { sw ->
  // And make a Binding for our script
  new Binding().with { b ->
    // Set 'out' in the Binding to be our StringWriter
    b[ 'out' ] = sw
    // evaluate the file with the GroovyShell (using the binding)
    new GroovyShell( b ).evaluate( new File( 's1.groovy' ) )
  }
  // And return the String captured in our writer
  sw.toString()
}

println output
```

And then run it with `groovy s2.groovy`

#### Edit

I think this is option #1 in Dave's answer...

Comment: I think you're right! I can't believe you just rewrote s1.groovy and s2.groovy willy-nilly.